# Laravel send email with markdown don't log

Tags: php, laravel, markdown

to send email I got the function:

```
public function build()
{
    if($this->tipoUsuario == 'paciente') {
        return $this->subject('Agendamento cancelado')
        ->markdown('emails.paciente.agendamento-cancelado', compact('tipoUsuario', 'sessao'));
    }
    else if($this->tipoUsuario == 'psicologo') {
        return $this->subject('Agendamento cancelado')
        ->markdown('emails.psicologo.agendamento-cancelado', compact('tipoUsuario', 'sessao'));
    }
}
```

That returns an error
[image]
But this error don't log in logs/larave.log. But if I change the function, like bellow, and force an error, like forgetting a semicolon, it writes the error to the log:

```
    public function build()
{
    if($this->tipoUsuario == 'paciente') {
        return $this->subject('Agendamento cancelado')
        ->markdown('emails.paciente.agendamento-cancelado')
            ->with([
                'tipoUsuario' => $this->tipoUsuario,
                'sessao' => $this->sessao,
            ]);
    }
    else if($this->tipoUsuario == 'psicologo') {
        return $this->subject('Agendamento cancelado')
        ->markdown('emails.psicologo.agendamento-cancelado')
        ->with([
            'tipoUsuario' => $this->tipoUsuario,
            'sessao' => $this->sessao,
        ]);
    }
}
```

How to logs errors when send email?

Comment: Start with https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/errors#report-method & https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/logging#writing-log-messages

Comment: I had tried all these solutions before and it didn't work